# integral of $\int_{0}^\frac{1}{e}\frac{(\ln x)^2}{x}\, dx?$

Tags: integration

I have an integral to solve and i'm blocked !
I did $$u = \ln x$$ and get the integral $$u^3/3$$ between $-\infty$ and $1$… but $\,\ln\,$ is not defined in $0\mkern1mu$?

thank you

Comment: You are correct.  The integral does not exist (or is infinite in the Lebesgue sense).

Comment: thank you, it reassures me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a change of variable $$u = -\ln x, x = e^{-u}, dx = -e^{-u} \, du$$  then $$ \int_0^{1/e} \frac{(\ln x)^2}{x}\, dx = \int_{\infty}^{1}u^2( -du) = \int_1^{\infty}u^2 du \to \infty$$

Comment: thank you ! (it was $ln^2(x)$ the edit was false sorry, but the result is the same)

Comment: @user3527451,you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was

$\displaystyle{\int \frac{1}{x \ln (x) \ln (x)} \, dx}$

between lower bound $x=0$ and upper bound $\frac{1}{e}$.

Now set $y=\ln (x)$, then $\text{dy}=\frac{\text{dx}}{x}$.

By substution we get:

$\displaystyle{\int \frac{1}{x \ln (x) \ln (x)} \, dx}=\int \frac{1}{y y} \, dy=\int \frac{1}{y^2} \, dy=-\frac{1}{y}$.

That is $F(x)=-\frac{1}{\ln (x)}$.

Calculating the bounderies, we have:

$F\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)-F(0)=1+0=1$

Value of integral exists.

Comment: I think that you did not treat the integral of the post.

Comment: Post was modified. First this integral has been posted.

Comment: So, you were perfectly correct. Cheers :-)